# How to control package structure with seam-gen

Tags: seam, seam-gen

I've been adding to an existing application by generating with seam-gen and adjusting from there.  One problem I keep having is that I have to spend a great deal of time editing the xhtml files to reflect package structure.

for example, seam-gen thinks this will work

```
   <s:decorate id="simplePidField" template="layout/edit.xhtml">
```

and so in every .xhtml, we have to change that to

```
   <s:decorate id="simplePidField" template="/layout/edit.xhtml">
```

This and other inconsistencies arise because seam-gen builds a flat directory with ALL of the xhtml files in one place, while our app has these divided and sub-divided into several directories.

Is there a way, in the reveng.xml file to define a package structure?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No not in the reveng.xml file. You have to look at the freemarker code in seam-gen source and adjust it there.

Look at the

```
seam-src/seam-gen/view/editproperty.xhtml.ftl
```

file and locate

`<s:decorate id="${componentProperty.name}Field" template="layout/edit.xhtml">` '

and

`<s:decorate id="${property.name}Field" template="layout/edit.xhtml">`'

and change those respectively.

---

Otherwise you just have to use search / replace functionality inside your view folder. This is probably just easier

Comment: Thanks!  This did the trick for the layout portion.  I'll note here that I changed the path in view.xhtml.ftl as well so it fixed the path to the template.xhtml in the ui:composition tag at the start of each of my xhtml files.